# coqIDE is not properly connecting files in project and is not compiling

Tags: coq, coqide

I'm new to using coq/coqIDE and I'm not computer savvy either so I don't know whats wrong or what to call the issue.  I was trying to go through the Software Foundations book, but coqIDE isn't working right.  I'm using the latest windows 10, and coqIDE 8.10.2

The first issue is when I go to the tab `compile -> compile buffer` in `Basics.v`, coqIDE doesn't create a .vo file or a .glob. None of the other buttons worked either.  Running coqIDE as admin didn't make it work either, but I figured out I can get around this by manually dragging Basics.v into the coqc application file.

I had no issues with coq working during the first lesson, but in the next lesson we're meant to import the definitions from `Basics.v` into `Induction.v`, when I run what they say

```
From LF Require Export Basics.
```

I get the error `The file C:\Users\...\Coq Files\Tutorial\lf\Basics.vo contains library Basics and not library LF.Basics` even though the _CoqProject file contains "-Q . LF" as it should.

I can get around this error too by just writing "Require Export Basics."
which properly loads, up until I actually try calling a definition from Basics

Running

```
Require Export Basics.
Example example: evenb 2 = true.
```

works until I get to evenb, and then gives the error
`The reference evenb was not found in the current environment.` even though it's in `Basics.v`

If I get even more anal and try

```
Add LoadPath "C:\Users\...\Coq Files\Tutorial\lf".
From LF Require Export Basics.
```

I get the error

```
Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix <> and prefix LF.
```

And then finally if I try

```
Add LoadPath "C:\Users\...\Coq Files\Tutorial\lf".
Require Export Basics.
Example example: evenb 2 = true.
```

Loads properly.

So I'm wondering how should I fix the load path so that the project works without putting that junk in every file and how do I make the compile tab work.

There were some people talking about "hitting make in the top-level" but I have no idea what that means.  I tried it anyway and ran the Makefile as a .bat even though I already downloaded it properly so there shouldn't be any need, but the Makefile didn't change anything anyway.

I don't think I'm forgetting anything, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of choosing `Compile > Compile buffer`, try `Compile > Make` instead (when browsing any one of the vernacular files in Logical Foundations) - I think that is what others meant by "hitting make in the top-level". But first, you may want to remove the workarounds you added in e.g. `Induction.v`, and save a trivial change in `Basics.v` such as adding/removing a newline somewhere in order to convince `make` to recompile it.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that.  I just tried it again, editing and saving Basics.v and then pressing `Compile > Make` didn't seem to do anything.  When I reincluded  `From LF Require Export Basics.` in Induction.v I got the same error as usual with that line `The file C:\Users\...\Coq Files\Tutorial\lf\Basics.vo contains library Basics and not library LF.Basics`

Comment: @Sigma maybe try manually deleting `Basics.vo` before retrying `Compile > Make` (with `Basics.v` or some other `.v` file in LF open)? See also: [coq/coq#5716](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/5716)

Comment: Didn't do anything, I tried reading through that thread and related ones, but I don't know enough about coding to follow what they're saying, thanks anyway.